# Python Beautiful Soup 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa5'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Iam encountering some weird characters while web scraping some elements of the page . The characters that seem to give error are :

> ? ??*??Á¢¢Á? /?? />? /??? ?/¢¥Á ??%% ?Á ?*????Á? ?> /???¥??> ¥? ¥©Á ?>¢¥/%%/¥??> ?Â >Á? Â?*Á ©???¢ ñ%Á?¥???/% Á%Á?¥??>?? />? Â??Á? ??¥?? ??¢¥????¥??> ¢`¢¥Á*¢ ??%% ?Á ??À?/?Á? ¥? _ÁÁ¥ ?>??Á/¢?>À Á????*Á>¥ ??*??¥Á? />? ??__?>??/¥??>¢ ?Á

My code concerned is as below

```
url= "http://www.nsf.gov#######@#@#@##";
    #webbrowser.open(url,new =new );
    flagcnt+=1
    if flagcnt%20==0: #autosleep for avoiding shut-out
        print "flagcount: "
        print flagcnt
        time.sleep(5)
     #Program Code extraction
    r = requests.get (url)
    sp=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Page : http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch

Iv read all pages on this error with some which suggest decoding and encoding but they dont seem to help.I dont know which encoding is being used here .Tried downgrading BS version but didnt help .
Any help is appreciated . 
Python 2.7  BS 4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me:

```
page_text = r.text.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')
page_soupy = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page_text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . It says on  page_soupy = BeautifulSoup(page_text) 'module' object is not callable . Any ideas :)

Comment: Ah, then you are importing the full module, not the function. I'll edit the answer.